# combine 2 different type of array in php

Tags: php

I want to combine 2 different set of arrays

**First Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => pacifica-aurum-pride-towers
            [getName] => pacifica-aurum-pride-towers
            [getImg] => test
            [getPrice] => 18
            [getPlace] => erode
        )
)
```

**Second Array**

```
Array
(
    [title] => New1
    [getName] => New name
    [getImg] => test
    [getPrice] => 18
    [getPlace] => erode
)
```

I need this answer from the above 2 different set of arrays

**Resultant Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => pacifica-aurum-pride-towers
            [getName] => pacifica-aurum-pride-towers
            [getImg] => test
            [getPrice] => 18
            [getPlace] => erode
        )
    [1]=>Array
        (
            [title] => New1
            [getName] => New name
            [getImg] => test
            [getPrice] => 18
            [getPlace] => erode
        )
)
```

Comment: First array is a multi dimensional array. second array is  one dimensional array. I want to get the resultant array is combined both

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing the following statement

`$array1[] = $array2;`

This adds `$array2` as an extra item to `$array1`

Answer (score 1):

Just append the second array to the first one, like this

```
$first = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => pacifica-aurum-pride-towers
            [getName] => pacifica-aurum-pride-towers
            [getImg] => test
            [getPrice] => 18
            [getPlace] => erode
        )

);

$second = Array
(
    [title] => New1
    [getName] => New name
    [getImg] => test
    [getPrice] => 18
    [getPlace] => erode
);

$first[] = $second;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_push if u want but defining a new index on ur first array works, actually the result will be the same.

```
$array1 = array(array('key1'=>'value011', 'key2' => 'value012'));
echo json_encode($array1);
/**
* output: [{"key1":"value011","key2":"value012"}]
*
*
*/
$arrayToPush = array('key1' => 'value021', 'key2' => 'value022');
array_push($array1, $arrayToPush);
echo json_encode($array1);
/**
* output: [{"key1":"value011","key2":"value012"}, {"key1":"value021","key2":"value022"}] 
*
*
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The most generic solution is to use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function

```
$result = array_merge($first, [$second]);
```

This way you will preserve the initial arrays and get the merged result into a new variable.